# XMLHttpRequest response fail if multiple asynchronous request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending requests to web server periodically. If I send one request every x seconds works as expected. But if send four requests every x seconds just get in responses 'xmlhttp.readyState = 1'

```
function send(value) 
    {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {

                console.log("Resp from " + value + ":='" + xmlhttp.responseText + "' readyState="+xmlhttp.readyState + " status=" + xmlhttp.status);

                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {           
                        //Process response


                    }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080?"+value, true);
            xmlhttp.send();     

    }
```

Example OK:

Here I get xmlhttp.readyState = 1,2,3,(4 + response)

```
setInterval( function() { send("cmd=0"); }, 1000 );
```

Example fail:

Here I get 'xmlhttp.readyState = 1' in all responses.

```
setInterval( function() { send("cmd=0"); }, 1000 );
setInterval( function() { send("cmd=1"); }, 1000 );
setInterval( function() { send("cmd=2"); }, 1000 );
setInterval( function() { send("cmd=3"); }, 1000 );
```

Request are correctly processed in server

Info:

- readyState = 1 -- > OPENED
- readyState = 2 -- > HEADERS_RECEIVED
- readyState = 3 -- > LOADING
- readyState = 4 -- > DONE